Portugol / problemas no código
Gostaria de criar um sistema no Portugol, com as seguintes informações:
Parte 1: geral
Parte 2: construir o menu
Parte 3: cadastrar hospede
Parte 4: exibir hospedes cadastrados
Parte 5: reservar área de lazer
Parte 6: exibir o total,
porém está dando problema na parte (1) geral do código, não estou sabendo identificar.
programa {
funcao inicio() {
cadeia vetorNomes[10]
cadeia vetorCPF[10]
inteiro vetorDias[10]
real vetorDespesas[10]
inteiro indiceHospede = 0
funcao inicio()
{
    inteiro opcao
    faca {
        opcao = mostrarMenu()
        escolha (opcao) {
            caso 1:
                cadastrarHospede()
                pare
            caso 2:
                exibirHospedes()
                pare
            caso 3:
                reservarAreaLazer()
                pare
            caso 4:
                calcularTotalAPagar()
                pare
            caso 0:
                escreva("Obrigado por usar nosso sistema!\n")
                pare
            caso contrario:
                escreva("Opção inválida, tente novamente.\n")
        }
    } enquanto (opcao != 0)
}

funcao inteiro mostrarMenu()
{
    limpa()
    escreva("1 - Cadastrar Hospedes\n")
    escreva("2 - Exibir Hospedes Cadastrados\n")
    escreva("3 - Reservar Área de Lazer\n")
    escreva("4 - Calcular total a pagar\n")
    escreva("0 - Sair\n")
    escreva("Escolha uma opção: ")
    retorne leiaInteiro()
}

procedimento cadastrarHospede()
{
    se (indiceHospede >= 10) {
        escreva("Os cadastros estão lotados.\n")
        retorne
    }
    escreva("Digite o nome do hóspede: ")
    vetorNomes[indiceHospede] = leiaCadeia()
    escreva("Digite o CPF do hóspede: ")
    vetorCPF[indiceHospede] = leiaCadeia()
    escreva("Digite a quantidade de dias que ficará hospedado: ")
    vetorDias[indiceHospede] = leiaInteiro()
    vetorDespesas[indiceHospede] = 0
    indiceHospede++
}

procedimento exibirHospedes()
{
    para (inteiro i = 0; i < indiceHospede; i++) {
        escreva("Índice: ", i, " Nome: ", vetorNomes[i], " CPF: ", vetorCPF[i], " Dias: ", vetorDias[i], " Despesas: R$", vetorDespesas[i], "\n")
    }
}

procedimento reservarAreaLazer()
{
    inteiro indice
    cadeia area

    exibirHospedes()
    escreva("Informe o índice do hóspede: ")
    indice = leiaInteiro()
    escreva("Escolha a área de lazer (A - Academia, S - Salão de Festas, R - Restaurante): ")
    area = leiaCadeia()

    escolha (area) {
        caso "A":
            vetorDespesas[indice] += 20
            pare
        caso "S":
            vetorDespesas[indice] += 50
            pare
        caso "R":
            vetorDespesas[indice] += 35
            pare
    }
}

funcao real calcularTotal(inteiro indice)
{
    retorne vetorDespesas[indice] + (vetorDias[indice] * 100)
}

procedimento calcularTotalAPagar()
{
    inteiro indice
    real total

    exibirHospedes()
    escreva("Informe o índice do hóspede para calcular o total a pagar: ")
    indice = leiaInteiro()
    total = calcularTotal(indice)
    escreva("O total a pagar pelo hóspede ", vetorNomes[indice], " é R$", total, "\n")
}

}
}
}

Deixei algumas instruções na sua pergunta original. Para evitar descentralização de informações o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas está disponível naquela postagem (pode editar aquela conforme o material passado).
